# Value dissapears on live site after editing DB value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an issue with a Wordpress premium theme and MySQL database. The value in the database box looks like this:

```
a:1{i:0;a:4{s:4:"name";s:9:"Trailer";s:6:"select";s:6:"iframe";s:6:"idioma";s:2:"en";s:3:"url";s:82:"https://youtube.com/sample.mp4
";}}
```

When I edit the YouTube link value to something else, the entire data in this box disappears on the live Wordpress page, although it is visible in the database even after refresh. I have no idea why this happens and how I can keep it from happening.

EDIT:
After i tried editing other values like post_title etc it just wont update the values at all on the live WP page.Why im doing this is because i need to add and edit mass amounts of data easily with scripts.

Comment: Are you sure you can't play with the settings directly in the wordpress admin?? It would be way safer.

Comment: The problem is I need to edit and insert data in mass amounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you are displaying is coming from PHP serialize. This is a way for PHP to stringify any value for later usage.

If you want to mass modify those values, your best bet is to create a PHP script that fetch the data, unserializes it, make change directly to the PHP variable it created, and serialize again to put to database.

If you want to play with the string directly, you will need to make sure you are careful.

The main reason why changing the URL of the youtube video doesn't work is because you might not be changing the string declaration too.

```
s:82:"https://youtube.com/sample.mp4";
```

This is invalid. It is split into 3 parts, using `:`. Type:Length:Value. So it is a string of length 82, yet you provide a 30 character string.

If you turn on NOTICE in PHP you will certainly see the errors about it.

EDIT:

After tinkering a bit on PHPFiddle.org I came up with a clean string from the one you gave, which has numerous flaws...

```
a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:7:"Trailer";s:6:"select";s:6:"iframe";s:6:"idioma";s:2:"en";s:3:"url";s:30:"https://youtube.com/sample.mp4";}}
```

Note that I changed the Length values in 2 parts, and added 2 semi-colon `:`

Comment: Well, it works now! Seems like the problem was in incorrect link lenght I entered. Thanks! EDIT: I actually got it working before I saw your updated reply by changeing the lenght, but your way seems to work too!